# Open url from textview with click

Tags: android, url, textview, listener, linkify

I am developing a chat app using RecycleView and I have managed to make the links on the messages clickable but not the way I wanted.

This is my listener:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new Chat_LVAdapter.RecyclerClickListener(this, recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
            Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "CLICK!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_message);

            textView.setLinksClickable(true);
            Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
            textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

            /*Intent intent = new Intent(Chat.this, WebViewer.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("url_web", extractUrls(textView.getText().toString()));
            startActivity(intent);*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
            TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_message);
            String msg = textView.getText().toString();
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            if(clipboard != null){
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("msg", msg);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            }
            Toast.makeText(Chat.this, R.string.texto_copiado, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }));
```

This is the TextView xml:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_chati_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
```

The problem comes with the `onClick` method. I can see the `Toast`, so the method works but it doesn't open the link. It only works if I double tap or if I long press. If I use the commented code, launching a `WebView` with an `Intent`, it works too. But I want to be able to use `Linkify` for emails etc.

Am I missing something? Why does the `Toast` work but not the `Linkify`?

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem of your algorithm you are making the text linkyfied at the first click so the second click will work fine. move this code :

```
TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_message);
textView.setLinksClickable(true);
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

to the recycler `ViewHolder`

Comment: I am not using a `ViewHolder`, I do all the work with `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Is that good practice or should I look into the `ViewHolder`?

Comment: in your case you can't use `Linkify` like that

Comment: Okey yeah, I am using `ViewHolder`. I use two, one for received messages and other for sent ones. I added the code but nothing changed.